# Why does ExecuteURL strip the existing headers where File doesn't?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, web-config, custom-error-pages

It seems to be generally known that serving custom error pages with a `responseMode` of `ExecuteURL` rather than `File` results in the HTTP status code not being maintained.

The remaining headers are also lost during the process resulting in no `cache-control` header being preserved and more.

What's really happening under the hood? Why are the headers not maintained?

I can find quite a lot of resources explaining the solution but nothing expanding on the reasoning for the problem in the first place.